# AWS ElastiCache Redis- How to use most recent daily backup upon cluster (with just 1 node, no Multi-AZ) restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, in-memory-database, amazon-elasticache

According to AWS ElastiCache documentation, a cluster loses all its data upon reboot: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/Clusters.Rebooting.html

> When you reboot a cluster, the cluster flushes all its data and
>   restarts its engine. During this process you cannot access the
>   cluster. Because the cluster flushed all its data, when the cluster is
>   available again, you are starting with an empty cluster.

The automatic daily backups can only be used in a **new cluster** to get a warm-started cluster:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-automatic.html

AOF file option has been disabled in Redis 2.8+ in AWS ElastiCache: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RedisAOF.html

How do we make AWS ElastiCache use the most recent daily backup data upon hardware failure/restarts

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for same thing but as of now it is not possible. Backup can only be used to build new cluster.